# parsing a json to a variable and from that variable fetch the value to a another variable

Tags: json, shell

This is not only about parsing a json. I am hitting a url using curl from where I am getting the json format and I want to store that json format in a variable. For an example: I have a json format like this:

```
[ {

    "abc": "abc.jsonTest.server.target",
        "bcd": [
                [
                66,
                123546789
                ],
                [
                null,
                165423579
                ]

        ]

}
]
```

I want to store this json in a variable like "y" and from that variable I want to fetch 66 and store in a variable "x".
I have tried

```
x= $(($y | jq .[0] | jq '.bcd[0]' | jq .[0]))
echo $y
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try like this, first set `y`:

```
$ y='[{                           

    "abc": "abc.jsonTest.server.target",
    "bcd": [
        [
            66,
            123546789
        ],
        [
            null,
            165423579
        ]

    ]

}]'
```

Test extracting the value:

```
$ echo $y | jq '.[].bcd[0][0]'
```

If that works then just save it into `x`:

```
$ x=$(echo $y | jq '.[].bcd[0][0]')
```

`x` should now contain `66`:

```
$ echo $x
66
```